# Rav Kook's full name

Tags: names, historical-figures, abraham-isaac-kook

Recently, I discovered that when the Rav Kook was sick before he died, a third name was added to his name - Yechizkiyahu. This can be seen in this sign calling to people to pray for him:

[image]

(image taken from [here](https://www.kedem-auctions.com/he/node/101764); can be found [here](https://web.nli.org.il/sites/nli/english/digitallibrary/pages/viewer.aspx?presentorid=NNL_Ephemera&DocID=NNL_Ephemera700105127) as well)

and in some of the newspapers reporting on his passing. See [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/newspapers/yarden/1935/09/02/01/article/4/?srpos=6&e=01-09-1935-03-09-1935--he-20--1--img-txIN%7CtxTI-%20%20%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%20%D7%90%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7%20%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A7-------%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%2C%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA------1) for example, pg. 2.

However, in other places, the name is never used. It isn't even on his tombstone:

[image]

Most people, to my knowledge, aren't even aware of this third name. Is it known why it was not used after his passing, in particular not inscribed on his tombstone?

Comment: How long before he passed away was the name added?

Comment: @JoelK I don't know. Is that the answer, that it depends on when the name was added?

Comment: I’m not sure, but possibly

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31174&st=&pgnum=20

Comment: @JoelK very interesting, thank you. I wonder why the Rabbinate of Tel Aviv-Jaffa kept that name on the מודעת אבל they put in the newspapers.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, most names added at the end of one's life for a refuah that ultimately doesn't happen are left off the person's name once they pass on.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות - do you have a source for this coz I heard the opposite?!

Comment: @Dov see the section in Gesher HaChaim which I linked to in my comment above

Comment: What is the name they added to Rav Ovadiah Yosef??

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Rav Chaim Michal Dov Weissmandl

Comment: @Dr you have heard R' Weissmandl referred to that way?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות https://hebrewbooks.org/42028

Comment: @Dr interesting. I have not heard people use that name, but you are definitely correct.

Comment: @Dov I also heard if the person didn't live twelve months after adding the name it doesn't stick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yom Tefila was on כ"ד תמוז תרצ"ה and HaRav Kook was Niftar on ג' אלול תרצ"ה.

Only if the person improved with the new name, then it is kept. See [here](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/200921) where there is a list of sources.

See [here](http://www.ravkooktorah.org/GIMMEL-ELUL-72.htm) in regards to Yahrzheit date.

Comment: Shkoyech. Any idea why in the מודעת אבל by the Rabbinate of Tel Aviv-Jaffa (which was also posted in other newspapers reading exactly the same) they included the new name?

Comment: @Harel13 Perhaps there was a question as to whether they should keep it or not. In the end the family I guess decided not to.